# Getting server error message when referencing getLastRow()+1

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I had a sheet that was working using some of the same code... In the last few days trying to work on my current project, stuff that used to work no longer works and I'm getting errors for all sorts of different stuff.

Currently, I can't move on until I figure this one out.

```js
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var clientList = ss.getSheetByName("ClientList");
var tracker = ss.getSheetByName("Tracker");

var tr_activeRow = tracker.getActiveCell().getRow();
var tr_clientName = tracker.getRange(tr_activeRow,1);
var tr_birthDate = tracker.getRange(tr_activeRow,5);

function addNewName() {
  if(tr_clientName.getValue() == "New" && tr_birthDate.getValue() != ""){
    tracker.getRange(tr_activeRow, 2, 1, 4).copyValuesToRange(clientList, 1, 4, clientList.getLastRow()+1, 1);
  }
}
```

When trying to run the code I get:

> We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again.

I've tried a few things and know that it's `getLastRow()+1` that's the problem. I also tried `getLastRow()` & `getLastRow()-1` to see if the code runs and it runs just fine. Only seems to be a problem when I'm using a positive integer...

What am I doing wrong?!? or is this a problem with sheets/apps script?

Comment: You're trying to copy content beyond the bounds of the spreadsheet. I'd kind of expect to get an error in that case.

Answer (score 0):

The parameters for `copyValuesToRange()` are:

> copyValuesToRange(sheet, column, columnEnd, row, rowEnd)

You are designating the row end to be row 1.

```
.copyValuesToRange(clientList, 1, 4, clientList.getLastRow()+1, 1);
```

The `rowEnd` should be a number that is bigger than or the same as (for one row) the `row` parameter.

Your are only getting one row,

```
tracker.getRange(tr_activeRow, 2, 1, 4).copyVa . . . .
```

so the `row` and `rowEnd` should be the same.

```
var theLastRow = clientList.getLastRow()+1;
tracker.getRange(tr_activeRow, 2, 1, 4)
  .copyValuesToRange(clientList, 1, 4, theLastRow, theLastRow);
```